# Divide two Pandas Pivoted Tables and generate third table with result of division between the two tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2, where

1) I have applied pivot table for df1, in which it contains sum of the ITEM VALUES IN THE TABLE.

Below is the python code

```
df_val = pd.pivot_table(df1, values = ['ITEM VALUE'], index=['B', 'C', 'D'], columns = ['Year','A'], aggfunc={'ITEM VALUE': sum})
```

[Pivot table of df_val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFDTl.png)

and

2) I have applied pivot table for df2 as well, in which it contains sum of the PART COUNT IN THE TABLE.

Below is the python code

```
df_cot = pd.pivot_table(df2, values = ['PART COUNT'], index=['B', 'C', 'D'], columns = ['Year','A'],aggfunc={'PART COUNT':sum})
```

[Pivot table of df_cot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akfHc.png)

**What I would like to achieve is to make new column "CPI DATA" to DataFrame df3 which should have the result of the division of column "PART COUNT" from df_cot with "ITEM VALUE" column from df_val.**

I have tried the code

```
df3['CPI DATA']= df_cot['PART COUNT'] / df_val['ITEM VALUE']
```

and the output was generated as 'NAN' for the column "CPI DATA".

**How to generate a third table with the result of division between two tables?
below is the required table which i want to generate..**

[Required OUTPUT table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBjUI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it up to you to figure out what you need to do with the inconsistencies between the two tables - some keys are present in one and not the other - but I would recommend not calculating across multiple tables and [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) them instead first.

If you only wanted to keep the entries that exist in both tables, you could do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_combined = pd.merge(df_cot, df_val, how = "inner", on = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "YEAR"])

df_combined["CPI DATA"] = df_combined["PART COUNT"] / df_combined["ITEM VALUE"]
```

Changing the `how` parameter to `left`, `right`, or `outer` will do different things in terms of keeping rows without corresponding entries in the other table, equivalent to [SQL JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)).

To me, it's a strong best practice to not manipulate over separate tables before joining since Panda's strong indexing structure could do plenty of things you don't expect.